# How to convert UNNEST function to legacy sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I am trying to understand Legacy SQL. I have this standart sql query

```
SELECT event_param.value.String_value
FROM `bike_app.info_firebase_ANDROID.app_events_20170521`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) as event,
  UNNEST(event.params) as event_param,
  UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) as user_prop
WHERE event.name = "add_mark"
  AND event_param.key = "item_id"
  AND user_prop.key = "age"
  AND (CAST(user_prop.value.value.string_value as FLOAT64)) > 10
```

which works perfectly as I want. But I can't catch how can I convert this query to legacy sql. Please, give me some advice.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use legacy SQL? If there is some issue preventing you from using standard SQL, the BigQuery team would like to know about it.

Comment: I am using Java API for connection to BigQuery. And this standart sql query always give me "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request" exception

Comment: I posted an answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146438/use-standart-sql-queries-in-java-bigquery-api) that should help.

Comment: What is the answer to question ?! Because I have the same need. I need to use decorators that not exists in Standard SQL.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard We use a BI system that is configured to run Legacy SQL. In order to create a BQ view that it can use we need to write that view in Legacy SQL.