# Use standard SQL queries in java bigquery API

Tags: google-bigquery, java

Is it possible to use standard SQL queries when using java bigquery API?
I am trying to execute query but it throws

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>   "message" : "11.3 - 11.56: Unrecognized type FLOAT64"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to use standard SQL with the BigQuery Java API. The first is to start your query text with `#standardSQL`, e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ...
FROM YourTable;
```

The second is to set `useLegacySql` to `false` as part of the `QueryJobConfiguration` object. For example (taken [from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#bigquery-enable-sql-java)):

```
public static void runStandardSqlQuery(String queryString)
    throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
  QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
      QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(queryString)
          // To use standard SQL syntax, set useLegacySql to false.
          // See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/
          .setUseLegacySql(false)
          .build();

  runQuery(queryConfig);
}
```