# UseLegacySql: false option in JobConfigurationQuery is ignored

Tags: google-bigquery, google-app-engine-go

Job declaration:

```
job, err := bqClient.Jobs.Insert(_PROJECT_ID_, &bigquery.Job{
    Configuration: &bigquery.JobConfiguration{
        Query: &bigquery.JobConfigurationQuery{
            UseLegacySql:        false,
            CreateDisposition:   "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            Query:               reportQuery.query,
            WriteDisposition:    "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            SchemaUpdateOptions: []string{"ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION", "ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"},
            DestinationTable: &bigquery.TableReference{
                ProjectId: _PROJECT_ID_,
                DatasetId: dataset,
                TableId:   "name$" + reportQuery.tableDecorator,
            },
        },
    },
}).Do()
```

The job finishes with error

`2017/07/19 11:41:27 ERROR: Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>`

`[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]`

The query starts with several `WITH ... AS (...)`.

What can I do?

Comment: Check Elliott's answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146438/use-standard-sql-queries-in-java-bigquery-api. Does it help you?

Comment: yep it fixed it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use standard SQL queries in java bigquery API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146438/use-standard-sql-queries-in-java-bigquery-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here [Use standard SQL queries in java bigquery API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146438/use-standard-sql-queries-in-java-bigquery-api)

A workaround is to put `#standardSQL` on top of the query